# Snowpark Python code perform SQL minus operation and find the column where the difference is?

Tags: python, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

```
Table 1
I'd Name Balance
1   AB   100
2   BC   200
```

Table 2

```
I'd Name Balance    
1   AB   110    
2   CD   200
```

Wanted to perform a minus between these two tables

```
Select I'd, Name, Balance from table1    
Minus    
Select I'd, Name, Balance from table2
```

Result will be

```
1  AB   100
```

I want to store only the column name and value from both table.

Snowflake Python worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Join the 2 tables and only select records where `balance` isn't same.

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID, TABLE1.NAME, TABLE1.BALANCE FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 
ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
AND TABLE1.NAME = TABLE2.NAME
WHERE TABLE1.BALANCE != TABLE2.BALANCE
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me rephrase the problem. This is a minus between source and target table where we do not know where the difference will be and in which column and need a snowpark Python not the simple sql

Comment: Minus operation is nothing but a left join and selecting where the rows don't match.